# Very Strange - Ubuntu messing up Windows LAN

Tags: networking, dual-boot, windows, lan

I am helping my friend migrate to Linux from Windows. So we installed Ubuntu 15.10 on his system. His current setup is Windows 10 + Ubuntu. Everything is going well except a very strange issue. **Windows can't connect to LAN if Ubuntu used LAN.**

This is what he does to reproduce the problem:

1. He boots into Windows 10 and shows me that he is able to access internet through his LAN.
2. He reboots to linux and connects to internet via LAN.
3. He boots back into Windows and suddenly he can't access the LAN.

I am very puzzled. How can Ubuntu mess with Windows LAN configuration?

Upon further investigation, we have observed that:

1. Windows LAN is messed up only if Ubuntu uses LAN. For example, if he used only WiFi in Ubuntu and never connected a LAN cable, there is no problem when he boots back to Windows.
2. It affects only LAN and not WiFi in Windows. So he is able to use WiFi in windows even when Ubuntu broke ethernet (LAN).
3. He found a temporary fix by following Anish A Kumar's answer (method 2 and 3) in [this](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_web/windows-socket-registry-entries-missing-according/5f54e033-9d49-4de0-bf23-576653641b20?auth=1) page.

I know I have only described the issue here, so ask in the comments for logs  that are required to debug the issue. I would really like to get to the bottom of this.

His laptop is a [HP Pavilion 15-ab032tx](http://support.hp.com/in-en/document/c04700593) and here is the output of [lspci -k](https://paste.ubuntu.com/15676378/) and [dmesg](https://paste.ubuntu.com/15676389/) to start with.

Comment: You should try updating the BIOS/UEFI, as it is one of the very few links between Ubuntu and Windows, and this is likely to be the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the Windows driver doesn't agree with the state Linux leaves the LAN hardware. Realtek is known for issues like this.

Try a `echo "options rtl8723be swenc=1 fwlps=0 ips=0" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8723be.conf` to make the module work in a more reliable state where Windows might be able to take over again from usage after Linux.

Explanation:

- **swenc**:using hardware crypto (default 0 [hardware])
- **ips**:using no link power save (default 1 is open)
- **fwlps**:using linked fw control power save (default 1 is open)

To make the values known to the driver, do

```
sudo service network-manager stop
sudo modprobe -rfv rtl8723be
sudo modprobe -v rtl8723be
sudo service network-manager start
```

before you use the LAN.

Comment: I think your solution seems to be working. A great find. I am waiting for him to test if everything about LAN is working before I accept this answer.